# Is there a way to activate local spark cluster that queries database directly?

Tags: sql-server, r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

I am attempting to use the `sparklyr` package to connect to an existing MS SQL database to query data faster than is possible with the `RODBC` package. Currently, I am able to successfully query the database using `RODBC::odbcConnect()` and `RODBC::sqlQuery()`. For most uses, this works fine, however, one of the databases I am querying stores extremely large amount of data and when my queries get close a million rows, it can take an extended period of time.

For example, when I query one of 40 possible sites using a wrapper function I wrote `read_sql`, from the beginning of this year (`2017-01-01`) to today (`2017-05-01`), there are roughly 800,000 rows and 7 columns in the resulting data frame. This function takes roughly 30 seconds to run.

```
> system.time(read_sql(site = list("1"), start_date = "2017-01-01", end_date = Sys.time()))
   user  system elapsed 
  19.25    0.41   33.07
```

and if I add a second site it takes almost double the time as the number of rows has also doubled to roughly 1.6 million:

```
> system.time(read_sql(site = list("1", "2"), start_date = "2017-01-01", end_date = Sys.time()))
   user  system elapsed 
  37.51    1.03   57.92
```

the `read_sql()` function essentially just converts the inputs into appropriate character strings to query the appropriate tables within the SQL database using `RODBC::sqlQuery()`.

I understand that there is a way to use SQL queries within spark in order to get desired outputs of spark tables. My question is whether there is a way to activate a local spark cluster that can query the database directly and hopefully speed up the wait time for larger queries.

Comment: Have a look at `?spark_read_jdbc`

Comment: Would i have to reconfigure the sql database to change from an odbc to a jdbc? I only have read rights to the database